# Getting all non function / decorated properties of a class in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to get all the properties of a typescript class that are not functions.  I'm not sure whether the fact that the properties will also be decorated can make the identification faster (If Typescript provides any way to use reflection to identify decorated properties?).

The end goal is to use these as keys to lookup the corresponding values, which will then be validated (Hence the annotations included in the example).  For example:

```
class A {
    @IsString()
    foo: string = "foo";
    @IsNumber()
    c: number = 2;
    d: ()=>...
}

let a:A = new A();
let properties = getPropertiesToValidate(a);

properties.forEach(p=>{

   value = a[p];
   //validate the value. 
});
```

### Update

Per @Titian comments the simplest and most efficient way to do this is to create a MetaClass instance.  The MetaClass mirrors the decorated class, but only stores the properties that were decorated on the original class.  We would create a MetaClass instance and set the `className` to `constructor.name` for the correspondng decorated class, and then just add the properties that were decorated to an array.  If anyone knows a simpler way please comment.

This is the current implementation I have in mind:

```
    /**
     * MetaClass stores the property names of the 
     * corresponding decorated class.  These can 
     * then be used to lookup validation contexts 
     * during object validation.
     */
    class MetaClass {
        /**
         * The name of the decorated class.
         */
        public className: string;

        /**
         * The properties that were decorated.
         */
        public properties: string[] = [];

        constructor(className: string) {
            this.className = className;
        }

        addProperty(property: string) {
            if (!this.properties.includes(property)) {
                this.properties.push(property);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the attributes under your control ? If so you could just modify them to collect the fields they are applied to.

Comment: Yes effectively - finishing up the validation framework right now: https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator

Comment: I'm considering creating a key out of each class constructor name, and then using it to lookup the properties that have validation decorators attached to them, but thought I would check whether there is a shorter, but just as efficient way of doing it first.

Comment: As far as I know there is no simple way to do this, but someone else may know better :)

Comment: Yeah I was hoping for some sort of direct lookup method (Avoiding the filtering based on their type), but I have a feeling that just creating that metadata during the application of the decorator is going to be the simplest and most efficient solution.